# Hadoop error in shuffle in fetcher#1

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm running a parsing job in hadoop, the source is a 11GB map file with about 900,000 binary records each representing an HTML file, the map extract links and write them to the context.
I have no reducer written for this job.

- When I run it on smaller files, of about 5GB with about 500,000 records it works ok.
- This is a single machine cluser
- The output has about 100 Million records, TEXT
- It failed after 11 maps tasks out of 200 planned.
- I'm running with Hadoop 0.22.0

I'm getting the following error:

> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error
>   in shuffle in fetcher#1 at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:124)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:362) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:223) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1153)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:217) Caused by:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.(BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.java:58)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.(BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.java:45)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MapOutput.(MapOutput.java:104)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManager.unconditionalReserve(MergeManager.java:267)

This is my mapreduce-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>Hadp01:8012</value>
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
  at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
  and reduce task.
  </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.local.dir</name>
  <value>/BigData1/MapReduce,/BigData2/MapReduce</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx1536m</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.max.xcievers</name>
        <value>2048</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb</name>
    <value>300</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>io.sort.mb</name>
    <value>300</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.task.io.sort.factor</name>
    <value>100</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>io.sort.factor</name>
    <value>100</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>tasktracker.http.threads</name>
    <value>80</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Anyone has any idea how to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you share your Mapper code? The error message looks like you're having a memory problem, which could mean you Key or Value object is potentially huge. What's the Key and Value types for your Map outputs?

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm aware of the potential problem of having a task that will consume a lot of memory.
I've ran the same task on a java application, by reading the map file and running the function and it finished all records with out any memory issue.
Plus the exception is failing the Reducer task and not the Mappper Task.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

this error caused by mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.memory.limit.percent,by default

```
mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.memory.limit.percent=0.25
```

To resolve this problem, I restrict my reduce's shuffle memory usage:
hive:

```
set mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.memory.limit.percent=0.15;
```

MapReduce:

```
job.getConfiguration().setStrings("mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.memory.limit.percent", "0.15");
```

[shuffle error solution](http://blog.csdn.net/mulangren1988/article/details/75371130)

Comment: That's a workaround that works fine for a certain extent. It appears even after reaching those limits.